# salesforce lwc - wire adaptor not able to have declared track variables as arguments

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I am trying to pull in picklist values of a field based on record type.
The below works -

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: 'Case', recordTypeId: '0123h000000kv04AAA' })
typePicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values)
        this.options = data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values;
    }
}
```

If I replace the ObjectAPIName & recordtype with a variable, it doesn't work -

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: '$this.objectName', recordTypeId: '$this.recordTypeId' })
typePicklistValues({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        console.log(data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values)
        this.options = data.picklistFieldValues.Type.values;
    }
}
```

All those variables have the actual values, which I checked already, is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [do not include `this` in reactive wire parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about).

Use

```
@wire(
    getPicklistValuesByRecordType, 
    { objectApiName: '$objectName', recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId' }
)
```

to achieve this reactivity.

Comment: Thanks David, I imported the object this way import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';, not sure how to import the recordtypeId to get the picklist values of that recordtypeid. could you show an example? Here is how my wire adapter is as of now @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '0123h000000kv04AAA' }), need to change the recordTypeId.

Comment: Seeing this from this link https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetPicklistValuesByRecordType/wireGetPicklistValuesByRecordType.js , should recordtypeId be hardcoded, I cant seem to find an example where a variable is used for the recordTypeId. Please advise.

Comment: Thanks David, I figured it out, was being dumb. Thanks again.